# Is there a standard way to proxy a socket connection?

Tags: sockets, proxy

What I want to do is to allow two separate entities that can not connect directly (let's say they're both behind a NAT) to be able to open a socket to each other.

Here is the best solution I can come up with:

- **A** → connects to well known address and requests a connection
- **A** ← response: two port numbers
- **A** → connects to well known address with first port number
- Second port number is manually communicated to **B** (not ideal, but acceptable)
- **B** → connects to well known address with second port number
- Messages are proxied between these two ports

Is there some better way to solve this problem? Is there some off-the-shelf solution that implements this or something like it?

Comment: Why two port numbers? Why *any* port numbers? All that A has to do is tell the proxy the target address, and all the proxy has to to do is try to connect to it, and communicate success or failure back to A, after which A either aborts or starts sending and receiving, on the same connection, which the proxy is relaying to and from the target. No further ports required at A.

Comment: As for standards have a look at [TURN - Traversal Using Relays around NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT)

Comment: Thanks. TURN (or more generally, ICE) is probably what I'm looking for. I'll check it out.

Comment: Also see [Hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)), which may be able to establish a connection through NATs without using a relay.  In general, these techniques fall under the umbrella of [NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal), which encompasses many different techniques.